# Why filling 2D array in javascript fails?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to fill a 2d array, and I have this code in javascript:

```
n=2; //rows
m=3; //columns
z=0;
array1=[];
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
        array1[i]=[];
        array1[i][j] = z;
        console.log(i+","+j+"="+z); //debug
        z++;
    }

}

console.log(array1);
```

But instead of getting this expected result;

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

I get:

```
[[undefined, undefined, 2], [undefined, undefined, 5]]
```

why!? I don't understand why I am getting *undefined* for all the items in each "inner" array, except the last one which is correct (here, the 2 and 5).

I made a debug step logging each `i,j` pair and the assigned `z` value, and i DO get the correct pair-values each time `(i,j=z)`:

```
0,0=0
0,1=1
0,2=2
1,0=3
1,1=4
1,2=5
```

so, I think I am correctly filling the array using `arr[i][j]=z` each time, so why does it get undefineds for those cases?
I also tried using the `arr=new Array()` instead of `arr=[]` syntax in both cases, but with the same result.

Any ideas? I'm almost sure it will be a trivial error, but I can't find what is wrong!.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd probably spot the error faster if you used meaningful variable names, such as row, rows, column, columns, and counter; instead of i, n, j, m, and z.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney this is an excellent suggestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are reinitializing the empty array in every loop iteration:

```
array1[i]=[];
```

When you should only be doing this once per value of `i`. Move the initialization out of the inner-most loop.

Comment: OH! I know it would be trivial, now I fell dumb. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it should be

```
n=2; //rows
m=3; //columns
z=0;
array1=[];
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    array1[i]=[];
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
        array1[i].push(z); // Here is my change
        console.log(i+","+j+"="+z); //debug
        z++;
    }

}
```